# QGIS having issue loading plugin "Profilefrompoints"

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I am having an issue when trying to run the plugin Profilefrompoints in QGIS. I believe it is because QGIS is calling on Python version 3.7.3 even though I downloaded Python 3.6.7 before QGIS. Error text follows at end.

```
QGIS version 3.4
Python version 3.6.7
MacOS Mojave 10.14.6
```

Couldn't load plugin 'ProfileFromPoints' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method

```
OSError: Could not find lib geos_c or load any of its variants ['/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libgeos_c.dylib', '/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/Current/GEOS', '/opt/local/lib/libgeos_c.dylib']. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 335, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "/Users/travissparrow/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ProfileFromPoints/__init__.py", line 34, in classFactory
    from .profileFromPoints import ProfileFromPoints
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 685, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/travissparrow/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ProfileFromPoints/profileFromPoints.py", line 31, in 
    from .profileFromPoints_dialog import ProfileFromPointsDialog
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 685, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/travissparrow/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/ProfileFromPoints/profileFromPoints_dialog.py", line 32, in 
    from shapely.geometry import Point
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 685, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/shapely/geometry/__init__.py", line 4, in 
    from .base import CAP_STYLE, JOIN_STYLE
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 685, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/shapely/geometry/base.py", line 17, in 
    from shapely.coords import CoordinateSequence
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 685, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/shapely/coords.py", line 8, in 
    from shapely.geos import lgeos
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 685, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/shapely/geos.py", line 111, in 
    _lgeos = load_dll('geos_c', fallbacks=alt_paths)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/shapely/geos.py", line 56, in load_dll
    libname, fallbacks or []))
OSError: Could not find lib geos_c or load any of its variants ['/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libgeos_c.dylib', '/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/Current/GEOS', '/opt/local/lib/libgeos_c.dylib'].
```

Python version: 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 09:23:15) [Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)] 
QGIS version: 3.4.13-Madeira Madeira, 64ad560274

Python Path:

```
/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python
/Users/travissparrow/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/Users/travissparrow/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins
/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python37.zip
/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/site-packages
/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/Resources/python
/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7
/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geos
/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
/Users/travissparrow/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the author of the plugin does not indicate it in the readme, it seems that he uses extra python modules that you might need to get it to work.

At a first glance in the code (e.g. https://github.com/jorgealmerio/ProfileFromPoints/blob/master/profileFromPoints_dialog.py) he seems to use at least numpy, shapely and matplotlib.

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I got into terminal and got all three of those packages downloaded and the problem with the plugin "profilefrompoints" persists. I consulted with someone else and it appeared to them that QGIS is calling on python version 3.7.3 at startup (the error from my comment above pops up when QGIS is starting up, not just when I try to use the plugin) and I have python version 3.6.7 installed on my machine. They seemed to think this was the larger issue, not having the missing modules. Any possible insight into that as the issue? thanks in advance

Comment: I'm afraid I do not. I am not conversant in python so can only marginally help you. It seems likely indeed (from the errors above) that you need python 3.7.